# How to make placeholder to be clickable?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I need to click "SEND" once mobile number is entered in the input. I am using bootstrap material design css. Below is the html code I am using Any helps would be appreciated.

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="mobile_no" class="bmd-label-floating form_input_label">Contact no</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control no-margin " id="mobile_no" style="width: 80%" placeholder="SEND">
</div>
```

CSS used is as below.

```
input[type="text"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    text-align: right;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #00bcd4;
}
```

Comment: A placeholder is just a placeholder it is not a button or something. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-placeholder

Comment: Don't abuse the placeholder attribute like that. Use it for what it means.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="SEND" />
```

You could add a button:

```
<button type="button">SEND</button>
```

Or you could wrap something in an  tag, as in:

```
<div class="form-group">
<a href="#">
   <label for="mobile_no" class="bmd-label-floating form_input_label">Contact no</label>
</a>
   <input type="text" class="form-control no-margin " id="mobile_no" style="width: 80%" placeholder="SEND">
</div>
```

The submit button is the most common solution.